# PHP assign multiple arrays to $_SESSION

Tags: php, arrays, class, session, assign

I have a problem when setting sessions, when I set a:
$_SESSION["predefinedvar"] = "SOMETHING"
It will remember the session variable, but however, when I do a:
$_SESSION = $class->somearray;
It won't save the session array.

I have searched the web, and tried the first few pages from Google from this search:
[php session assign array](https://www.google.no/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=php%20session%20assign%20array&oq=php%20session%20assign%20array&gs_l=hp.3..0i8i30l2.203407.2276319.0.2276455.73.59.9.0.0.9.437.7252.25j27j4j0j1.57.0.les;..1.0...1c.1.p1F4wXALQxA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b8689432b7f4d2e8&bpcl=38897761&ion=1&biw=1920&bih=955)

The output is similar to this when I do an print_r($_SESSION) or print_r($l->details);
This is the output the script gives me (both from $_SESSION and $l->details)

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] => Usernamehere
            [password] => EnCryptedPasswordHere
            [mail] => em@il.com
            [ip] => ::1
            [registerred] => 1349111531
            [loggedin] => 0
            [vip] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [city] => 1
            [family] => 0
            [pm] => 0
            [mod] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [url] => images/pb/1.png
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [rank] => 1
            [subrank] => 5000
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [hp] => 100
            [str] => 0
            [def] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [money] => 0
            [bank] => 0
            [bullets] => 0
            [points] => 0
        )

)
```

Currently I have the following codes

login.c.php

```
<?php
if(!$required) die("Du har ikke adgang til denne filen.");

class login {

    var $username, $password;
    var $details;
    var $salt = "SALTHIDDEN";
    var $error;
    var $justcheck;

    function onPost($username, $password, $justcheck = FALSE) {
        if($justcheck) $this->justcheck = $justcheck;
        if(!$username || !$password) die("Du må skrive inn både brukernavn og passord.");
        $this->username = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($username));
        $this->password = sha1(md5($this->salt . $password));
    }

    function checkDetails() {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$this->username."' AND password = '".$this->password."' LIMIT 1");
        $num = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($num > 0) {
            $this->details[1] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            $this->error[] = "Feil brukernavn eller passord.";
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    function getEverything() {
        $this->details[2] = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_c WHERE id='".$this->details[1][id]."' LIMIT 1"));
        $this->details[3] = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_p WHERE id='".$this->details[1][id]."' LIMIT 1"));
        $this->details[4] = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_r WHERE id='".$this->details[1][id]."' LIMIT 1"));
        $this->details[5] = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_s WHERE id='".$this->details[1][id]."' LIMIT 1"));
        $this->details[6] = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_i WHERE id='".$this->details[1][id]."' LIMIT 1"));
    }
    function returnValue() {
        if($this->error) foreach($this->error as $e) echo "$e<br />";
        if(!$this->justcheck && !$this->error) die("<a href=\"#main\">Du er nå innlogget som $username<br />Klikk her hvis du ikke viderekobles til hovedkvarteret.</a><meta http-equiv=\"Refresh\" content=\"0; url=#main\">");
    }

}
```

and this file is the POST.php file:

```
<?php

require_once("path/hidden/db.php");

switch(key($_GET)) {
    default:
        echo "Nothing to do here";
    break;

    case "login":
        $required = TRUE;
        require_once("path/hidden/login.c.php");
        session_start();
        $l = new login();
        $l->onPost($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]);
        if($l->checkDetails()) {
            $l->getEverything();
            session_start();
            $_SESSION = $l->details;
        }
        $_SESSION[RandomVar] = "RandomVal";
        //$l->returnValue();
        print_r($_SESSION);
        print_r($l->details);
        //echo session_id();
    break;
}
```

Comment: test to name the session. $_SESSION['user_details'] = $l->details

Comment: Thanks, just did it when I saw the answer from Pé de Leão and it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign a name for the Session variable. You tried the following:

```
 $_SESSION = $class->somearray
```

But you need to assign a key for your array:

```
$_SESSION['my_array'] = $class->somearray
```

Comment: Ahh, so it isn't enough for it to get the ID from an array?
Anyway, thank you, it worked :D

Answer (score 1):

for storing an array into session you need to bind that array with key.

e.g     $_SESSION['key']=$array_variable;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$_SESSION = $l->details;
```

Try this:

```
foreach($l->details as $strKey => $strValue) {
    $_SESSION[ $strKey ] = $strValue;
}
```